# Event Receiver Item Added for Multiple Files uploaded

Tags: 2007, list, sql-server, event-receivers

I am trying to add few details for a item that is added to a list to SQL database table using a stored procedure, it works perfectly but when I upload multiple files it adds all of the items into the database, whereas My requirement is to just add 1 any of them Item details in the database, not sure if I can do it or not, here is the code.

```
    public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
    base.ItemAdded(properties);

   // System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(false);
    SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
        {

            SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString());
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("InsertItemDetails", sqlConnection);
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            command.Parameters.Add("@SiteURL", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = properties.WebUrl;

            command.Parameters.Add("@ItemName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = properties.ListItem.Title;

            command.Parameters.Add("@TimeItemAdded", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now;

            sqlConnection.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            sqlConnection.Close();
        });
}
```

I think I can add a filter for URL as if it already exists in database then delete that row and add a new Item, but not sure if it will be effective solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created two more stored procedures,

1. One for checking if any item exists in table
2. Second to delete all records associated to item details of added item

so first I check if item details are in DB if they are then delete them and add a new item new details.

Hope it helps if someone else came across same problem :)